# SQL Which constructions to use for selection hard logic queries in single table

Tags: sql, select, records, repeat

let's imagine that i have a simple table like this:
id - record id
char_id - character id
level_id - level id, that available for character

this is content example:
0 1 1
1 1 2
what's mean that character with id 1 has access to levels 1 and 2.

What keywords or constructions i need to use, if i want to get:
char_id of those characters, that has access to any two levels?
char_id of those, who has access to single level only and no more?
char_id of those, who has same levels available?
char_id of those, who has different levels available?

that blows my mind... could anyone recommend something?

Comment: no, i just trying to understand that things. i don't ever need complete solutions, just a keywords, that can help me

Comment: @Kosmos: In your example, the record id is 0 for both records.

Comment: thanks Mark Bannister, i missed it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two options, use `HAVING`:

```
-- To check for access to levels 1 and 2
SELECT char_id
FROM MyTable
WHERE level_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY Char_Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

-- to check for access to only one (unspecified) level
SELECT char_id
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Char_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

The other two options you need to elaborate some more.

Do you only want exact matches between different char_ids?  As in, these two characters both have access to the exact same list of levels?

The last option would just be the opposite of the above once you work out what exactly you want.

Comment: thanks for the first examples! and about the last two things. yes, would be good to know characters, that has access to exactly same list of levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading up on the [HAVING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) SQL clause that should get you going.